# Manual type inference in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference

Consider the function

```
f g h x y = g (g x) (h y)
```

What is its type? Obviously I can just use `:t f` to find out, but if I need to deduce this manually, what's the best way to go about this?

The method I have been shown is to assign types to parameters and deduce from there - e.g. `x :: a`, `y :: b` gives us that `g :: a -> c` and `h :: b -> d` for some `c`,`d` (from `g x`, `h y`) and then we keep on making deductions from there (`c = a` from `g (g x) (h y)` etc.).

However this sometimes just turns into a huge mess and often I'm not sure how to make further deductions or work out when I'm done. Other problems sometimes happen - for instance, in this case `x` will turn out to be a function, but that was not obvious to me before cheating and looking up the type.

Is there a specific algorithm that will always work (and is reasonable for a human to execute quickly)? Otherwise, are there some heuristics or tips that I am missing?

Comment: Well the algorithm that Haskell uses is *Algorithm W* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system#Algorithm_W

Comment: But I find it a bit weird why it produces a mess. Typically the idea is that you assign a type to the parameters, and later make it more specific, sometimes introducing new type variables, or removing some given two are basically the same, etc.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm afraid that having never studied logic or philosophy (yet) this algorithm isn't of any help to me.

Comment: @A.Moris: well I don't really understand what you expect as an answer. The algorithm cited is not made more complex than it should be. There is a rather short implementation (https://github.com/wh5a/Algorithm-W-Step-By-Step/blob/master/AlgorithmW.pdf). Yes it takes some work, since typically an algorithm has to encode what is for some humans "common sense", but a machine has no common sense.

Comment: I think it's best to think heuristically in pieces with interesting patterns: for this problem, g (g x) - this is a function (because later it takes (h y) as a parameter) and because of its recursively called nature it suggests g has type (a -> a).  From there the rest probably flows more easily?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem At minimum, an explanation of how to deduce the type of the function given.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's inspect the function at the top level:

```
f g h x y = g (g x) (h y)
```

We will begin by assigning names to types, then going along and specialising them as we learn more about the function.

Firstly, let's assign a type to the top expression. Let's call it `a`:

```
g (g x) (h y) :: a
```

Let's take the first argument out and assign types respectively:

```
-- 'expanding'  (g (g x)) (h y) :: a
h y :: b
g (g x) :: b -> a
```

And again

```
-- 'expanding' g (g x) :: b -> a
g x :: c
g :: c -> b -> a
```

And again

```
-- 'expanding' g x :: c
x :: d
g :: d -> c
```

But hold on: we now have that `g :: c -> b -> a` and that `g :: d -> c`. So by inspection, we know that `c` and `d` are equivalent (written `c ~ d`) and also that `c ~ b -> a`.

This can be inferred by simply comparing the two types for `g` that we have inferred. Note that this is *not* a type contradiction, since the type variables are general enough to fit their equivalents. This *would* be a contradiction if we had inferred, for instance, that `Int ~ Bool` somewhere.

So we now have the following information in total: (a little work omitted)

```
y :: e
h :: e -> b
x :: b -> a             -- Originally d, applied d ~ b -> a.
g :: (b -> a) -> b -> a -- Originally c -> b -> a, applied c ~ b -> a
```

This was done by substituting the most specific form of each type variable, that is substituting `c` and `d` for the more specific `b -> a`.

So, simply inspecting which arguments go where, we see that

```
f :: ((b -> a) -> b -> a) -> (e -> b) -> (b -> a) -> e -> a
```

This is confirmed by GHC.

Answer (score 6):

Well the function is:

```
f g h x y = g (g x) (h y)
```

or more verbose:

```
f g h x y = (g (g x)) (h y)
```

Intially we assume that all the four parameters (`g`, `h`, `x`, and `y`) have different types. We also introduce an output type for our function (here `t`):

```
g :: a
h :: b
x :: c
y :: d
f g h x y :: t
```

But now we are going to perform some inference. We see for example `g x`, so this means that there is a function application with `g` the function, and `x` the parameter. This means that `g` is a function, with as input type `c`, so we redefine the type of `g` to:

```
g :: a ~ (c -> e)
h :: b
x :: c
y :: d
f g h x y :: t
```

(here the tilde `~` means that two types are the same, so `a` is the same as `c -> e`)).

Since `g` has type `g :: c -> e`, and `x` has type `c`, this thus means that the result of the function application `g x` has type `g x :: e`.

We see another function application, `g` as function, and `g x` as argument. So this means that the input type of `g` (which is `c`), should be equal to the type of `g x` (which is `e`), hence we know that `c ~ e`, so the types now are:

```
     c ~ e
g :: a ~ (c -> c)
h :: b
x :: c
y :: d
f g h x y :: t
```

Now we see a function application with `h` the function, and `y` the argument. So that means that `h` is a function, and the input type is the same as the type of `y :: d`, so `h` has type `d -> f`, so that means:

```
     c ~ e
g :: a ~ (c -> c)
h :: b ~ (d -> f)
x :: c
y :: d
f g h x y :: t
```

finally we see a function application with `g (g x)` the function, and `h y` the argument, so that means that the ouput type of `g (g x) :: c` should be a function, with `f` as input type, and `t` as output type, so that means that `c ~ (f -> t)`, and therefore:

```
     c ~ e
     c ~ (f -> t)
g :: a ~ (c -> c) ~ ((f -> t) -> (f -> t))
h :: b ~ (d -> f)
x :: (f -> t)
y :: d
f g h x y :: t
```

So that means that since `f` has those parameters `g`, `h`, `x` and `y`, the type of `f` is:

```
f :: ((f -> t) -> (f -> t)) -> (d -> f) -> (f -> t) -> d -> t
--   \_________ __________/    \__ ___/    \__ ___/    |
--             v                  v           v        |
--             g                  h           x        y
```

Answer (score 3):

You already described how to do it, but maybe you missed the unification step.  That is, sometimes we know that two variables are the same:

```
x :: a
y :: b
g :: a -> b    -- from g x
h :: c -> d    -- from h y
a ~ b          -- from g (g x)
```

We know that `a` and `b` are the same, because we passed `g x`, a `b`, to `g`, which expects an `a`.  So now we replace all the `b`s with `a`, and keep going until we have considered all subexpressions...

With regard to your "huge mess" comment, I have a couple things to say:

1. This is the way to do it.  If it's too hard, you just need to *practice*, and it will get easier.  You will start to develop an intuition and it will come more easily.
2. This particular function is not an easy function to do.  I've been programming Haskell for 12 years and I still need to go through the unification algorithm on paper for this one.  The fact that it is so abstract doesn't help -- if I knew what this function's purpose was it would be much easer.

Answer (score 2):

Simply write down all the entities' types under them:

```
f g h x y = g (g x)   (h y) 
                 x :: x  y :: y
                       h :: y -> a            , h y :: a
               g :: x -> b                    , g x :: b
            g    :: b -> (a -> t)             , x ~ b , b ~ (a -> t)
f :: (x -> b) -> (y -> a) -> x -> y -> t      , x ~ b , b ~ (a -> t)
f :: (b -> b) -> (y -> a) -> b -> y -> t      , b ~ (a -> t)
--       g           h       x    y
```

Thus `f :: ((a -> t) -> (a -> t)) -> (y -> a) -> (a -> t) -> y -> t`. That's all.

Indeed,

```
~> :t let f g h x y = g (g x) (h y) in f
    :: ((t1 -> t) -> t1 -> t) -> (t2 -> t1) -> (t1 -> t) -> t2 -> t
```

---

This goes like this:

1. `x` must have some type, let's call it `x`: `x :: x`.
2. `y` must have some type, let's call it `y`: `y :: y`.
3. `h y` must have some type, let's call it `a`: `h y :: a`. hence `h :: y -> a`.
4. `g x` must have some type, let's call it `b`: `g x :: b`. hence `g :: x -> b`.
5. `g _ _` must have some type, let's call it `t`. hence `g :: b -> a -> t`.
   which is the same as `g :: b -> (a -> t)`.
6. the two type signatures for `g` must *unify*, i.e. be the same under some *substitution* of type variables involved, since the two signatures describe the same entity, `g`.
   thus we must have `x ~ b, b ~ (a -> t)`. This is the substitution.
7. Having all the types of the arguments to `f`, we know it produces what `g` produces, i.e. `t`. So we can write down its type, `(x -> b) -> (y -> a) -> x -> y -> t`.
8. Lastly, we substitute the types according to the substitution, to reduce the number of type variables involved. Thus we substitute `b` for `x` first, and then `a -> t` for `b`, each time removing the eliminated type variable from the substitution.
9. When the substitution is empty, we are DONE.

Of course we could have chosen to replace `b` with `x` at first, ending up with the substitution `x ~ (a -> t)`, and then we'd end up with the same type in the end, *if we always replace the simpler types with the more complex ones* (like, replacing `b` with `(a -> t)`, and *not* vice versa).

Simple steps, guaranteed results.

---

Here's another attempt at shorter / clearer derivation. We focus on the fact that `g x` serves as `g`'s argument, thus `g x :: x` (and the trivial part still remains, `h y :: a`):

```
f g h x y = g (g x)   (h y)      {- g :: g , h :: h , x :: x , y :: y
  g h x y        x       y                 , g x   :: x   -- !
                  x       a      t         , g x a :: t
                                               x a :: t  ... x ~ a->t
f :: g             ->h     ->x     ->y->t
f :: (x     ->x   )->(y->a)->x     ->y->t 
f :: ((a->t)->a->t)->(y->a)->(a->t)->y->t      -}
```

Pretty simple after all.

The last argument in the definition can be elided, as `f g h x = (g . g) x . h`.